# Permission denied when create file in mac os using electron

Tags: macos, electron

I have created electronjs application and also created `dmg` file for mac os. In  my application I am creating file when application execute first time.

But `mac` giving an error like `permission denied to create file`.

I have did like `var stream = fs.createWriteStream("desktop.db");`